# I need to create a function that find the sum of the first N (passed as arguments) whole numbers

Tags: r

**Function that find the sum of the first N (passed as arguments) whole numbers and return in V**

```
 sum_whole <- function(a){ 
    for (i in a){
     V <- a[1]+a 
    } 
    print(V) 
    }


print(sum_whole(20))
print(sum_whole(32))
print(sum_whole(4))
```

Comment: Can you clarify a little more? An example of your expected result would be helpful.

Comment: Not sure what you need but a func that sums the first N wholes could be: `sum_whole<- function(N){
   nums <- seq(1, N-1)
   Reduce("+", nums)
 }`.

Comment: `sum(head(a, N))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Rui Barradas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8245406/rui-barradas) mentioned, `sum()` is a straightforward approach:

```r
Sum_whole <- function(N) {
    sum(seq_len(N))
}
Sum_whole(5)
#> [1] 15
```

You can also use a reduce function. Here are two examples: one in base R and one using the purrr package from the tidyverse.

A base R version:

```r
Sum_whole <- function(N) {
    Reduce(`+`, seq_len(N))
}
Sum_whole(5)
#> [1] 15
```

A tidyverse version using purrr:

```r
library(purrr)
Sum_whole <- function(N) {
    purrr::reduce(seq_len(N), `+`)
}
Sum_whole(5)
#> [1] 15
```

Comment: Thanks Michael regards :)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the question just this one-liner?
There even is a formula for the [sum of the first terms `N` of an arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum).

```
Sum_whole <- function(N) N*(N + 1L)/2L

Sum_whole(5)
#[1] 15
Sum_whole(43)
#[1] 946
```